# possible to grab all installed apps in sharepoint?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm attempting to create a custom home page for Sharepoint 2013 which will operate similarly to the promoted links app - displaying all the apps installed by a user in a metro style interface.

The promoted links app works great, but my issue is that we want users to be able to install their own apps from the app catalog without having to edit the promoted links list to display it on the home page.

Is it possible to grab the url's / names of all the apps installed by a user from a web part?

Comment: Here's an existing answer that might help [http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70628/get-list-of-installed-apps-using-client-object-model][1]


  [1]: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70628/get-list-of-installed-apps-using-client-object-model

Answer (score 1):

Use [SP.AppCatalog.getAppInstances Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj850839(v=office.15).aspx) to retrieve `AppInstance` objects installed on an instance of SharePoint:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var appInstances = SP.AppCatalog.getAppInstances(ctx, web);
ctx.load(appInstances);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
  function () {
     //iterate apps  
     for(var i = 0; i < appInstances.get_count();i++) {
        //...
     }

  } , 
  function (sender, args) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(args));
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by Vadim is what I attempted first, but I found it did not return the apps installed. After a few trial and errors I discovered it was because I needed to look at the root web rather than the web where the app was installed.

So, in summary, my version is pretty much identical except for how the web is set:

```
web = ctx.get_site().get_rootWeb();
```